# How do I add components from top to bottom in VBox?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm currently working on a project using JavaFX, where I need a list. The problem is that I cannot use the listview, because I might need multiple components for one entry.

Right now I'm using a VBox to add the components. The problem here is that I want the newest entry to be added in the top of the VBox, rather than in the bottom of the VBox.

It seems like I cannot add images, so I've uploaded my examples to Imgur:
http://imgur.com/a/Nc1sU

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the proper index when adding items:

```
public class VBoxSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        VBox vBox1 = new VBox();
        for( int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            vBox1.getChildren().add( new Text( "Item " + i));
        }

        VBox vBox2 = new VBox();
        for( int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            vBox2.getChildren().add( 0, new Text( "Item " + i)); // add on top
        }

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setSpacing(20);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(vBox1, vBox2);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane( hBox), 300, 250));
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh, this method seems to be both nice and effective. :)